# On a Kobo Glo how do you change the desktop/screen saver?

Tags: kobo, kobo-glo

I have recommended books from Kobo on the screen saver/desktop and I want to delete it as well as a few other things. Is there a 'manage your desktop' facility?

Comment: By "desktop" you mean the main screen of your ereader?